# Cannot find 'ResourceOptions' in scope

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am trying to make a simple mapbox map iOS app. I followed the installation guide (triple checking the netrc file) and copy pasted the "Display a simple map view" example. I get the error "Cannot find 'ResourceOptions' in scope".

See the code below...note it is example code from mapbox and is not mine...

```
import UIKit
import MapboxMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    internal var mapView: MapView!

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a map view.
        let myResourceOptions = ResourceOptions(accessToken: "your_public_access_token") //error here
        let myMapInitOptions = MapInitOptions(resourceOptions: myResourceOptions) //error here
        mapView = MapView(frame: view.bounds, mapInitOptions: myMapInitOptions)

        // Center the map camera over Stockholm.
        mapView.mapboxMap.setCamera(
            to: CameraOptions(
                center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                    latitude: 59.31,
                    longitude: 18.06
                ),
                zoom: 9.0
            )
        )

        // Add the map.
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
    }
}
```

I have done the troubleshooting steps mapbox provides (clean build, cache, etc.), remade my entire simple app, reading the docs, and tried googling this error. Apparently, nothing works and google doesn't provide much. Please advise.

Comment: at which point in your code are you getting the error?

Comment: @flanker two lines with myResourceOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had the wrong github version during mapbox installation.

"To install a specific version, set the Dependency Rule field to one of the version-based options and insert the desired version. The latest stable version of the Maps SDK is 10.16.0."

Comment: What does this mean? Github is a website. How do you have the wrong version of a website?

Comment: @HangarRash I needed to use version 10.16.0 and not "up to next major version". I messed up installation.